# Getting "Creating default object from empty value" exception msg but getCode() returns 0

Tags: php, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2.* and PHP 5.5.8 I have a try catch block that's properly trapping the warning, 'Creating default object from empty value'.  However the getCode() call returns 0.

Is there any way of setting my environment so that this, and other exceptions ALWAYS return a non-zero value for getCode()? (Note I'm already trapping for PDOExceptions where getCode returns a string.)

```
try{
    //do something that causes the above exception;
catch($e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
}
```

The point of the post, is not what's causing the error, but that $e->getCode() returns a 0 value.  I suppose there is no guaranteed value using getCode() as it is dependent on what unknown code throws the exception.

Comment: can you show you code please

Answer (score 0):

```
(Note I'm already trapping for PDOExceptions where getCode returns a string.)
```

Not sure how you are getting `string` back from this method...

According to the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php, the `getCode()` method on the exception object `Gets the Exception code`.

I.e.

```
<?php
try {
    throw new Exception("Some error message", 30);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "The exception code is: " . $e->getCode();
}
?>
```

Will output:

```
The exception code is: 30
```

So, if you are getting `0` from `getCode()` method, it's most likely an exception that being thrown without explicitly setting the exception code. e.g. `throw new Exception("An error has occurred");`

Comment: Sort of what I figured.  Thanks